# Problem installing rms package due to issues with MatrixModels package

Tags: r, macos, install.packages

On my Mac. I have installed the rms package in R. When trying to load the package I get the following error message:

```
library(rms)
```

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rms’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘MatrixModels’

I then try:

```
install.packages("MatrixModels")
```

This generates a very long output, finishing with:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../AMD.a(amd_i_dump.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../AMD.a(amd_l_dump.o) has no symbols
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -DNTIMER  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c SuiteSparse_config.c -o SuiteSparse_config.o
ar -rucs ../SuiteSparse_config.a SuiteSparse_config.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o Matrix.so CHMfactor.o Csparse.o init.o Mutils.o bind.o chm_common.o coerce.o cs.o cs_utils.o dense.o dgCMatrix.o dgeMatrix.o factorizations.o kappa.o sparseVector.o abIndex.o packedMatrix.o products.o unpackedMatrix.o sparse.o subscript.o validity.o CHOLMOD.a COLAMD.a AMD.a SuiteSparse_config.a -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Matrix’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Matrix’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Matrix’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘MatrixModels’ ...
** package ‘MatrixModels’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘Matrix’ 1.5-1 is being loaded, but >= 1.6.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘MatrixModels’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/MatrixModels’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘MatrixModels’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/50/kh0h3dds7hzdmnbcdypxrtb80000gq/T/RtmpW5Hzvm/downloaded_packages’
```

If I then try to install Matrix, this as well doesnt work:

```
> install.packages("Matrix")
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Matrix’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Matrix’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Matrix’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/50/kh0h3dds7hzdmnbcdypxrtb80000gq/T/RtmpxdA2VZ/downloaded_packages’
```

It is beyond my knowledge how to try to troubleshoot here, thus I am asking. Has anyone experienced similar problems and if so, found a solution for it? It might be of relevance to say that I am working on a job computer where I dont have complete administrator rights (however I manage to install and load all other packages I need).

Comment: Run `install.packages("Matrix")` to update Matrix to version 1.6-1, as the latest MatrixModels depends on Matrix >= 1.6-0.

Comment: Should probably have added that, I also tried this. Please see updated question. Trying to install "Matrix" generates a similar error message.

Comment: When asked whether you want to install from source or binary (even if source version is newer), choose "binary".

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, this worked by installing Matrix, MatrixModels, and mvtnorm using type = "binary".

Answer (score 1):

**The solution, as pointed out in the comments section was to:**

```
install.packages(c("Matrix", "MatrixModels", "mvtnorm"), type = "binary")
install.packages("rms")
library(rms)
```